# Can I pass in outerHeight when rebuild grid in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

In ng-grid there are three components.

Toppanel, Viewport, Footpanel

Height of Viewport is calculated by outerHeight(height of the grid) - height of top and footer panel.

I was trying to rebuild the grid with the height I passed in every time I click a button. 
The grid looks fine, but the viewport is too short.

I found out that is because when I clicked the button outerHeight in calculation didn't update.

How can I solve this problem.

I use

```
$scope.gridOptions.$gridServices.DomUtilityService.RebuildGrid(
        $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope
        $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h=height that I set;

$scope.gridOptions.$gridServices.DomUtilityService.RebuildGrid(
        $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope
        $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid
        );    
$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.rootDim.outerHeight=h;
```

That solve my problem.